# How to explicitly load shell interpreter in a C program

Tags: linux, shell-script, c

I want to create an **executable script** which is not **readable/writable**

However since an interpreter needs to read this file it is not possible to do so directly. Therefore I wanted to know if I could explicitly load an interpreter into a C program along with my script.

This would allow me to set the permission of the C program according to my needs.

Comment: Your C wrapper is going to use `setuid`?  If your question is simply about how to call the shell executable from a C program, this sounds more like a question for [StackOverflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com) to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call shell scripts from C application using `system()` function:

> system()  executes  a  command specified in command by calling /bin/sh
>   -c command, and returns after the command has been completed.  During execution of the command, SIGCHLD
>          will be blocked, and SIGINT and SIGQUIT will be ignored.

Example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    char* command = "\
for i in 1 2 3 4 5;\
    do echo \"$i\"; \
done";

    system(command);
    return 0;
}
```

Running:

```
$ gcc test.c -o test
$ chmod 100 test
$ ./test
1
2
3
4
5
```

Remember that argument is a command string so you have to terminate lines with semicolons. You also have to escape quotation marks.